# Prevent application to post PreventUserIdleSystemSleep

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, sleep-wake, power-management

Listing processes which keep my MBP awake with `pmset -g assertions` shows some applications which I positively do not wish to be able to influence power management.

```
pid 150(coreaudiod): [0x0000f9a400019c4e] 00:10:34 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.audio.00-16-94-2e-19-7e:output.context.preventuseridlesleep" 
Created for PID: 3455.
```

Is there a generic way to tell the system that for example `coreaudiod` can never post such a PreventUserIdleSystemSleep assertion?

Note that I'm not interested in hunting individual options for each process/application - I am looking for something like `pmset --ignore correaudiod` which positively restricts processes. Is there such a feature?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no user accessible approach for blocking [power assertions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1557134-iopmassertioncreatewithname) in macOS.

If you would like this feature in macOS, please [let Apple know](https://www.apple.com/feedback).